# Algorithm to extract outer SVG path

Tags: algorithm, svg

I'd like to extract the outer path (red line) of A and B circles (or other paths/shapes), and erase all the inner lines, so there would  be only one path (perhaps a little bit of a complicated one). Is there any algorithm that could do this easily?

[image: circles]
<sub>(source: [candelalearning.com](https://courses.candelalearning.com/zelixmth151/wp-content/uploads/sites/1212/2015/11/Fig3_1_1.png))</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by "extract" and "erase"? Can you be more specific about what you already have and what your problem is?

Comment: I think the question is clear. I have two circles and want to have one red path (See the image)

Comment: If you have two _imaginary_ circles and you need to _draw_ the outer path, then I think it's really doable by using `<path d="">`; but if you already have two `<circle>` and need to _highlight_ the outer path, I think that's difficult. That's why I ask.

Comment: The reason of my question is that I'd like to minimize the cnc knife path, so I guess this is more like 'highlighting' the outer path of two circles.

Comment: You could use the javascript library [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) to compute the [convex hull](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Hull-Geom) of your two circles. The vertices in the convex hull are all on the desired path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term you are looking for is `bezier path boolean operations`, specifically `union` for the case you are presenting (this should help you googling).

Paper.js has a [javascript implementation](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/6aa9f94f93eb987274e4bc2761f3fdee714da324/src/path/PathItem.Boolean.js):

You can [see the examples here](http://hkrish.com/playground/paperjs/booleanStudy.html).

[image]

Comment: The Internet page is long gone by now, so the way to go is to download a library archive from the developers' site: http://paperjs.org/download/, unpack it, then go to "examples\scripts" subfolder and there open "BooleanIOperations.html" in a browser.

However, the question is: what if I only have one (not two as in the library) path string which represents a complex internal shape but I want to extract only the outer part of the path? Is there an algorithm/library for that?